# If $f'(2x)=g(x)$, is there and way to define $f'(x)$ in terms of $g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was working on a problem recently and came across a case where I knew that $f'(2x)=g(x)$, but the problem required that I solve for $f(x)$ or at least for $f'(x)$ is there any way to do this in a general fashion.
Here is my attempt:

$$f'(2x)=g(x)$$

$$f(2x)=\int_0^x g(x) \,dx$$

But anything after there is a mystery to me. I tried something that I'm unsure about to solve for $x$, unsure how useful that would be.

$$2x=f^{-1}\left(\int_0^x g(x) \,dx\right)$$

$$x=\frac{f^{-1}(\int_0^x g(x) \,dx)}2$$

Comment: Why is $f$ invertible?  Why not just use $f'(x)=g\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$?  Also, you shouldn't write $\int_0^x g(x)dx$ because the variable $x$ takes two roles, instead, you mean $\int_0^x g(t)dt$.

Comment: We have $f'(x)=g(x/2)$ and $f(x)=\int_0^{x/2}g(t)\,\mathrm dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'(2x)=g (x)\implies f'(x)=g (\frac x 2) $$

$$\implies f(x)=\int_a^x g (\frac t 2)dt$$

put  $t=2u $
then
$$f (x)=2\int_b^{\frac x 2} g (u)du $$

Comment: I'm sorry but were did a&b come from, and why make the transition from u to t?

Comment: @AaronQuitta a real b=a/2

Comment: Yes I understand how they relate but what is your underlining motivation behind making the transition?

Comment: To avoid using the constant $+C $.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid it?

Comment: You have the choice. if $F'(x)=G (x) $ then $F (x)=\int_a^x G (t)dt $ or $F (x)=\int^x G (t)dt+C $